# Django / Python Media rendering not working

Tags: python, django, file-upload, media

Can anyone explain to me what is happening here? I am able to upload images from the admin panel, and the frontend to the 'media/company/logo1.png' folders. its working, and when I delete the folder it re-creates it, no issue.

In development I am unable to render the image from the django admin panel, as clicking the image link to view returns "Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server." with the URL "http://13.59.234.9/media/company/mnmade-logo.png"

```
# Settings.py
import os

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Models.py
class Company(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
image=models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to="company/")
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
objects = CompanyManager()
# add for manager validator

class Meta:
    ordering = (
        'id',
        'name',
        'image',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    )

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


# projects URLS.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('reports/', include('reports.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('company/', include('company.urls')),
    path('employees/', include('employees.urls')),
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# Views
def manage_admin(request):
    if 'admin_id' not in request.session:
        return redirect('/signin-company-admin')

    company = Company.objects.get(admins=request.session['admin_id'])

   context = {
        'admin': Admin.objects.get(id=request.session['admin_id']),
        'all_admins': Admin.objects.filter(company=request.session['company_id']),
        'company': company,
        'locations': Location.objects.filter(company=company.id)
    }


return render(request, 'manage-admins.html', context)

# App URLS.py
path('manage/admin', views.manage_admin),

# HTML
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ company.image.url }}" alt="{{ company.name }}" />
```

The image rendering appears to be working on my local repo, by on aws this issue I can't solve.

Comment: You might need to allow /media/ folder in your (Nginx/Apache) configuration file. Can you please share your web server config

Comment: @AhmedAblak That was exactly my issue, thank you!